# Download Result of Source Destination (Web Audio API)

Tags: web-audio-api

I'm building a tool to edit audio with the Web Audio API.

Here is where I'm stuck:

```
...
    source
    .connect(gainNode)
    .connect(analyser)
    .connect(analyser2)
    .connect(audioCtx.destination);
};
```

What I've written (which ends with the code above) successfully allows the user to upload a file, apply effects, and listen to it on play(). How would I then allow the user to click a button to export the results to a WAV file?

I've tried several methods online that have not worked for my use case.

Please let me know if more code is needed. Thank you for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a WAV file, I think you have to do that yourself.  WAV files are quite simple.  In this case, you'll need to add either a `ScriptProcessorNode` or `AudioWorkletNode` just before the destination to capture all the audio and convert it to a WAV file that can be downloaded.

If a compressed file is ok, you can look into [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) to save the data for you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm looking into how that would be accomplished. Once the data is captured by the AudioWorkletNode, would I be able to implement a button that kicked off the download? Possibly even with the audio playing?

Comment: Lots of details are missing, but generally, you should be able to do this.  It should be a problem to download while playing.  You just need to make sure you copy the data out before creating the WAV file.  If you can deal with WAV files with float32 values, this is pretty straightforward.  I've not done this myself, but I did write up some simple things to save audio, but it was for the output from an `OfflineAudioContext`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by writing an entirely different script to download the file using OfflineAudioContext.

My original script plays the audio with effects, and the second script downloads it with the same effects. Now to figure out why there is latency on the effects while using OfflineAudioContext.